# Checkout Payment gateway not working with onestepcheckout in magento 1

Tags: magento-1, payment-gateway, onestepcheckout

Checkout payment method module is working with default one-page checkout but when I am trying to use it with magestore Onestepcheckout, it's not working.

Anyone have an idea about that.

Comment: We need more informations error version of magento